# SharePoint 2013 - How to search / filter results of a list view web part?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, I created a site page. From the ribbon, I added a web part, then added my custom document library to the page.  I now see my document library on my site page with the proper columns I have set through the web properties.

My question is this, what other web part do I need to add to this same page to filter my list view based on a file name?  Meaning...On this same site page, I want an input box, at top, that I can type "cat" into. And once I click submit, the list view will find all documents that have the word cat in it.

Is this possible for a custom site page in SharePoint 2013?

Is there anyway to tie the search box web part to a list view of a document library?  When I attempted this process the search box did not recognize other web parts on the page, even though I have a list view on the page.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked this http://www.techmikael.com/2015/03/how-to-unexpectedly-block-usage-of.html

Comment: also you can use content search web part..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the search box for the list web part.

Edit the page, edit the listview webpart and at the bottom of the settings, under Miscellaneous, check "Display Search Box". Save the page.

[image]

This will add a search box above the items and it will let you search in the specific list directly, instead of using the site search.

Comment: thank you so much Christoffer.  Turning that one was extremley easy, but I do have a problem.  That search box is not reterning back any results, no matter what I try to find (the filename, modified by, the date,etc) nothing shows up.  Is there a way to (1) configure this specific search box to talk to my list view? or (2) is there another search web part I can add to page that will talk to my list view?

Comment: First thing would be to make sure that the content of the library or list is crawled and exist in the index as this is a must for the search to work. So check you crawl schedules and make sure that the content is in the index.

Comment: I did, and these documents have been live and available to access for over a year now through another publishing page that has a search results web part on it.  For some reason, on the oslo theme, search results don't work at all on site pages or document libraries.  Yet I can get all my documents to return fine on my publishing pages.

Comment: I never heard of such thing, sadly. Is it tied specifically to using the Oslo masterpage? Is version history enabled on the document library?

Comment: Regardless of my search crawling/results issue, your answer was direct to my specific problem - thank you for investigating that!